# detect if background tab is opened in javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, tabs, detect

How to determine if a background tab "`_blank`" was opened from a current page using javascript or jQuery
such that when a user opens a background tab from a current window, number of times opened label gets incremented by 1 in that current window.

for example if some link was clicked such that

```
$(a).target('_blank').click(function(){
var numberoftimesopenedvalue += 1;
$("#numberoftimesopenedlabel").val("numberoftimesopenedvalue");
})
```

is this the correct way,will I get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work,

On every click you are attempting to create a new variable, and in doing this you are attempting to add 1 to the current value which is not yet set. This would error i would imagine.

Then when assigning this value to the label you are actually assigning a string.

You need to get the current value before adding to it and updating.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this approach:

```
var numberOfTabsOpened = 0

$('a[target="_blank"]').click(function() {
    $('#label').html(++numberOfTabsOpened);
});
```

The `numberOfTabsOpened` will increment on every click on the link with `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you create a counter as a global variable and then use this counter within your script it could work.

js:

```
var counter = 1;

function openWindow(href) {
window.open(href, "pop-up/tab" + counter + "top=400,left=400");

counter++;
}
```

html:

```
<a href="javascript: openWindow('http://hotail.com/');">Open a new Window/Pop-up</a>
```

I Think the counter would indicate how many times the window was opened.